# Россия, Пруссия, Белоруссия — удвоенная С говорит о чем-то общем?

Tags: этимология

Существует ли какая-либо связь между словами *Россия, Пруссия и Белоруссия*? Ой-ой, вопрос неверно сформулирован. Понимаю, что между словами Россия и Белоруссия связь есть. А вот Пруссия. Почему в этом слове пишется удвоенная согласная *С*?

Могу предположить, что это всё из-за лигатуры эсцет (SS). Написание на языке-оригинале: Preussen (эсцета нет на клавиатуре, поэтому использовал двойную S).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Почему в этом слове пишется удвоенная согласная С?

От немецкого Preußen – Пруссия. Немецкий диграф *эсцет* (ß) передали удвоенным **С**.
Вообще-то пруссы не были германцами, относились к балтийской группе, близкой к литовцам, но еще в XVi-XVII веках онемечились. Поэтому пруссы и Пруссия вошли во все языки через немецкий.

Answer (score 3):

Пруссия - это от пруссов. Вполне такой "летописный" народ, живший в тех местах до германского завоевания.

А, вот, "Русь Великая, Малая и Белая" - действительно связаны исторически. Ну, а об сдвоенную "с" в слове "Россия" тут уже копья ломали..

Answer (score -2):

Да, связь есть — это общий корень РУС.
Народ, живший в древности, назывался *порусами*, его соседи — поморцы, поляки, беларусы. Очевидно, что порусы — этнографическая часть большого русского этноса, смешавшегося с балтами и далее асиммилированного немцами.

Answer (score -2):

Есть связь. Изначально русь - это викинги с территории современной Дании и Швеции. В повести временных лет написано: "В год 6370 [862 по современному летоисчислению]… Пошли за море к варягам, к руси. Те варяги назывались русью, как другие называются шведы, а иные — норманны и англы, а еще иные готы — вот так и эти. Сказали руси чудь, славяне, кривичи и весь: «Земля наша велика и..." . НА самом деле этих викингов и звать не нужно было. В те далекие времена имела место активная экспансия викингов в Европу и даже в Азию и Африку. Эрик Рыжий даже доплыл до Америки. Короче, в то время как одни племена (или союзы, объединения) осаждали Италию, Британию и т.п., то варяжская русь воевала земли балтов, славян и финно-угров на пути из Варяг в Греки, а также на водных путях вдоль Волги, Днепра, Двины. Благодаря названию этих русов земли, которые контролировались ими и стали называться Русь и другими вариациями на эту же тему и с этим корнем: Руотси, Русь, Рось, Россия, Боруссия, Пруссия, Русланд, Раша ...

Comment: Модно посмотреть на источник этого Откровения? Задорнова и Фоменку не предлагать.